# Transfrom XML to CSV with XSLT, correlating elements by attribute values

Tags: xml, csv, xslt

I am trying to transform XML to CSV using XSLT.  The values in the CSV are coming from /data/measValue/r (readings), where each reading is correlated to its type via the "p" attribute of the "r" tag (see below for an example).  I only want a subset of the measTypes, in the example below just op1-op4 (I don't care about op5).  I think XSLT is the right way to transform this to CSV, but I'm not sure how I can correlate the reading values to the correct measType.  Also, I'm new to XSLT, so I'm wading through a lot of new concepts.

Input:

```
<data type="A">
    <measType p="1">op1</measType>
    <measType p="3">op2</measType>
    <measType p="4">op3</measType>
    <measType p="6">op4</measType>
    <measType p="7">op5</measType>
    <measValue label="label1">
        <r p="1">100</r>
        <r p="3">200</r>
        <r p="4">150</r>
        <r p="6">50</r>
        <r p="7">300</r>
    </measValue>
</data>
```

Desired output (with header):

```
label,op1,op2,op3,op4
label1,100,200,150,50
```

Also, if an operation is missing, I want to output an empty field in the CSV (or zero-valued).

E.g., if op2 was not in the XML, the output should be like this:

```
label,op1,op2,op3,op4
label1,100,,150,50
```

Pseudo logic

```
template for data
    apply-templates for measType
template for measType
    Find p value corresponding to op1 and apply-templates for r with matching p value
    Find p value corresponding to op2 and apply-templates for r with matching p value
    Find p value corresponding to op3 and apply-templates for r with matching p value
    Find p value corresponding to op4 and apply-templates for r with matching p value
template for r
    print value
```

I can use XSLT 1.0 (via xsltproc) or 2.0 (via saxonb-xslt).

Comment: Please state which version of XSLT your processor supports.

Comment: XSLT 1.0 or 2.0.  I installed a 2.0 processor (saxonb-xslt)

Answer (score 2):

Use a key and perhaps just

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  version="2.0"
  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  exclude-result-prefixes="xs">

  <xsl:param name="types" as="xs:string*" select="'op1', 'op2', 'op3', 'op4'"/>
  
  <xsl:output method="text"/>
  
  <xsl:key name="type" match="measType" use="@p"/>

  <xsl:template match="data">
    <xsl:value-of select="'label', $types" separator=","/>
    <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="measValue"/>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:template match="measValue">
    <xsl:value-of select="@label, r[key('type', @p)[. = $types]]" separator=","/>
    <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

It will output the right `r` values though the order is taken from their sequence inside the `measValue`, not based on the `measType` order. For your sample it didn't seem to matter.

For the order and with your additional requirement change the `value-of` to

```
<xsl:value-of select="@label, for $t in $types return string(r[key('type', @p)[. = $t]])" separator=","/>
```

Comment: Thanks Martin!  This really helps.  I updated a requirement in the OP since I didn't think of it initially.  Empty values should be printed in the event that "opX" is missing (completely absent) from the XML data file.

Comment: Awesome, thanks!